# Gitlab merge from a specific source branch

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-branch

I have a branch in gitlab called `devops` and i want to merge my `master` branch with `devops` branch. However, i do not want any other branch to issue a merge request with `devops` branch. Is it possible?

Basically, for `devops` as the target branch while merging, only `master` can be the source branch. Can some customizations be done to be able to do this? Or by using any scripts?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to tell GitLab which branches that are allowed to be merged into which other branches. If you are using GitLab CI there is a way to achieve what you want though.

If you go to your project on GitLab, then to Settings -> General -> Merge Requests. There you will find a checkbox that says "Only allow merge requests to be merged if the pipeline succeeds".

Then you have to set up a pipeline for your project, and you should be able to find tutorials and documentation for this. There are then two environment variables called "CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME" and "CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME". These are set by GitLab when the pipeline is running in a merge request context.

Here is a list of all variables that are predefined.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#predefined-environment-variables

You can then set up a job that is run before all other jobs, but only if there is a merge request. There is no use to check these variables otherwise! An example can look like this:

```
stages:
  - merge-check
  - build
  - test

allowed-merge:
  stage: merge-check
  script:
    - check-branches # This command is different depending on if you run cmd/bash 
  only:
   - merge_requests
```

The script for checking the branch name can look different depending on where your gitlab runner is executing. It should check these two environment variables and return 0 if the branches are correct and return 1 otherwise.

Doing it this way doesn't stop the merge requests from being created, but there is no way to accept a merge request that doesn't follow the rules that you want.