# How to enforce code changes have gone through lower environments first before production release?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are using GitLab for the source control. I am new to gitlab pipeline and yaml file.

Our current gitflow is:  `feature branch -> dev branch-> qa branch->release branch`
1>Developer creates feature branch -> make changes-> and then create merge request (MR) into `dev` branch.
2>We perform peer review -> approve MR into `dev` branch.
3>Upon approval and merge, pipeline triggers automated deployment to `development` environment from the `dev` branch.
4>Developer test changes in development environment.
5>All good? Then Developer create MR from `dev` branch to `qa` branch.
6>Upon approval and merge, pipeline triggers automated deployment to  `qa` environment from the `qa` branch.
7>The step 1 to 6 are repeated for each feature we develop in the current sprint.
8>At the end of the sprint, upon QA certification, maintainer merges `qa` branch to `release` branch.
9>merging into release branch requires 2 approvals.
10>Upon merge approval into `release` branch DOES NOT trigger automated deployment. Using the pipeline, we trigger the deployment pipeline manually from the release branch.

```
default:  
  tags:
    - my-gitlab-runner
stages:
 - build:default
 - deploy:dev
 - deploy:qa
 - deploy:prod 

workflow:
  rules:    
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"

# we want to build code on all branches
build-default:
  image: "myimage"
  stage: build:default
  script:        
    - npm install
    - npm i -g @nestjs/cli    
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "build_output.zip"
    expire_in: 6 hrs  

deploy-dev:
  image: "myimage"
  stage: deploy:dev
  environment: 
    name: dev
    url: "https://dev.mydomain.com"
  script:    
    - deploy/scripts/deploy-dev.sh    
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"  

deploy-qa:
  image: "myimage"
  stage: deploy:qa
  environment: 
    name: qa
    url: "https://qa.mydomain.com"
  script:    
    - deploy/scripts/deploy-qa.sh    
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "qa"  

deploy-prod:
  image: "myimage"
  stage: deploy:prod
  environment: 
    name: prod
    url: "https://prod.mydomain.com"
  script:    
    - deploy/scripts/deploy-prod.sh
  when: manual    
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "release"
```

This flow is been working fine.

But with this flow it is possible to create a new branch -> make changes -> then create merge request into the release branch to deploy to production. Whilst this would require approvals, but there is no mechanism in the pipeline to ensure that the changes must have gone through lower environments (dev/qa) first.

How can pipeline enforce the rule that it must not be possible to release to production before current sprint changes have gone through lower environments?

**UPDATE 1**
I created `verify-merge` job that runs as very first job in the pipeline on `merge_request_event`. This job checks for source and target branch and the jobs fails or success depends on the branches being merged

```
verify-merge:
   script:    
    - deploy/scripts/verify-merge.sh
   rules:
     - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

However issue here is user can still create MR while the pipeline is running. Consider this scenario
1>User creates feature branch -> push the branch to GitLab ->this triggers `build` and `unit test` job on feature branch.
2>While pipeline is running user can create MR into dev branch -> this triggers another pipeline on `merge_request_event` with single job `verify-merge`
3>`verify-merge` pipeline will complete earlier than the first build/test pipeline
4>This will allow approver to approve and merge the MR because GitLab's merge request check only checks for the latest pipeline successful or not.
5>So even though the first pipeline is still running or failed changes will be merged into `dev` branch

[image]

Comment: First though that comes to mind is to use branch protection rules to prevent merging of changes without the required reviews. If you don't want to task the reviewers with making sure that changes have been deployed to dev first (I don't see why this is a big deal, but your dev cycle may be different from what I'm used to), you could use a plugin that does that validation for you.

Comment: We need to keep the approval process because it not only approves the MR but also make sure the code follows the coding standards and nothing unwanted is committed.

Comment: Can't you just limit the source branches with a script or gated checkin? So the only branch that is allowed to merge into `release` is `qa`, and the only branch allowed to merge into `qa` is `dev`. (Obviously you can make exceptions for hotfixes.)

Comment: Side Note, I feel like step 5 could be problematic because "All good" has to mean all features that were checked into `dev` are good, not just the one any particular developer is working on. I use a similar workflow as this, but step 5 merges the feature branch into `qa` (rebasing it if necessary so it doesn't bring in anything else from the `dev` branch). Since `dev` is inherently filled with a lot of test code that doesn't make the cut, we reset `dev` to `qa` at the start of every sprint.

Comment: @TTT I Like the idea of gated check in using script. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625789/gitlab-merge-from-a-specific-source-branch
However, even though developer create a merge request, the value of `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`  is always `push`.  I wanted add script when `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` merge_request_event. (ofcourse I will change the workflow rule accordingly)